# GKE - Kube-DNS resolution to VPN network

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

New to GCloud and GKE and having a frustrating time with DNS.

We have a VPN between our office and GCloud running a Shared VPC.  Existing firewall rules seem to work fine. We can ping both ways, we can ssh to Google successfully.

So now from within GKE, we need to be able to resolve hostnames across the VPN using DNS.  Should be simple.

I edited the kube-dns config map and added our internal domain name using stubDomains pointing to our two DNS servers.  After the kube-dns pods get redeployed, I verified that in the logs, they are getting the new stubDomain section.  However I still can't resolve any hosts, even from the kube-dns containers themselves.

While logged into dnsmasq container:

```
/etc/k8s/dns/dnsmasq-nanny # cat stubDomains
{"internal.domain.com": ["10.85.128.5", "10.85.128.6"]}

/ # nslookup google.com
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

Name:      google.com
Address 1: 108.177.9.138 ox-in-f138.1e100.net
Address 2: 108.177.9.101 ox-in-f101.1e100.net
Address 3: 108.177.9.139 ox-in-f139.1e100.net
Address 4: 108.177.9.100 ox-in-f100.1e100.net
Address 5: 108.177.9.102 ox-in-f102.1e100.net
Address 6: 108.177.9.113 ox-in-f113.1e100.net
Address 7: 2607:f8b0:4003:c13::71 ox-in-x71.1e100.net

/etc/k8s/dns/dnsmasq-nanny # cd /
/ # nslookup rancher.internal.domain.com
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

nslookup: can't resolve 'rancher.internal.domain.com': Name does not resolve

nslookup: can't resolve 'rancher.internal.domain.com': Name does not resolve
/ # nslookup rancher.internal.domain.com 10.85.128.5
Server:    10.85.128.5
Address 1: 10.85.128.5

nslookup: can't resolve 'rancher.internal.domain.com': Name does not resolve
```

Now as far as I can tell, the Egress is supposed to be an explicit allow from Google to anything else.

But just in case, I added an egress rule to allow TCP/UDP 53 to the servers.  No luck either.

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you provide the kube-dns configmap?

Comment: So it looks like I got the stubDomain working for containers that use kube-dns.  But we also have containers that are using the Node IP, and the Node DNS settings to use Kube-DNS, so now we're stuck again.

Comment: that explains it, so you'll need to update resolv.conf to include your private nameservers. The problem there is that the nodes resolv.conf is replaced by the metadata server whenever the DHCP lease is renewed

Comment: you can run a daemonset that updates your resolv.conf file to append your private nameservers then lock down the file using chmod

Comment: Is there a way to do it for every new cluster, or do I have to manually add the resolve.conf entry on each node every time?  Seems exceptionally cumbersome in an environment that changes frequently.

Comment: if you use a daemonset (you can just use the same one for every cluster), the daemonset will spin up a pod on every new node and make the change, like a startup script. You can use [this example of a startup script](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/startup-script) for k8s

Comment: I think we're still barking up the slightly wrong tree.  To test I edited resolved.conf, added my upstream DNS servers, and it still refuses to resolve any hostnames in the other domain.  I can see the query hitting the VPC firewall, but nothing happens after that.

Comment: Got it.  Turns out that our VPN tunnel goes down very quickly, and the tunnel can only be initiated from our office, not Gcloud.  Once I bought the tunnel up, with the changes I made to resolved.conf, everything seems to be working.  I guess we'll have to put an IPSLA on the VPN tunnel routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recap our discussion in the comments for the greater public:

You can use the kube-DNS configmap to add stubDomains which your pods will use for name resolution. Once the configmap is changed, the kube-dns pods needs to be recreated for the change to take effect. Any pod using default dns settings ([clusterFirst is the default](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)) will resolve using kube-dns.

Pods using the "default" setting for the dns config (resolve against node resolv.conf) will ignore the stubDomains configured in the configmap. Instead, we need to update the nodes resolve.conf file.

There are two things to note for this.
1) The resolv.conf file on every GCE VM (nodes included) is [overwritten by the metadata server whenever the DHCP lease is renewed](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#resolv.conf).
2) There is no way to programmatically append dns entries during cluster creation.

To address this, use a [daemonset as a startup script](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/startup-script) that will append the new additional nameservers to the the resolv.conf file and then, to ensure the metadata server does not revert the file back, [make the file immutable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67508/how-do-i-make-a-file-not-modifiable)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying a guess because we don't have your GKE cluster configuration but I already encounter something similar and I bet you didn't configure IP Aliasing https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips

A little explanation: you can't access a vpc pearing from another vpc pearing, that mean that if you are in a VPC, you can't access a managed service from a shared connection to another project or your office (through a vpn ipsec tunneling I suppose). As GKE is a managed service, by default it will live inside a private network and open a pearing to your project so you can't use a lot of thing (prometheus for monitoring or do DNS resolution as the cluster won't know how to join your other network).

IP Aliasing is resolving this fact by creating the cluster inside the network of your project, so that you can access, your cluter in the same ip range as the rest of your project and use vpc pearing.

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the shot - unfortunately when using a Shared VPC, you have to use Alias IP's in the cluster.  I can see in the VPC firewall logs that queries are being "allowed" through the VPC firewall, but never arriving at our VPN.  Strange.

Comment: If you have ip aliasing you have subnets, did you create the routes for the cluster inside the VPN?

Comment: Routes are there, I can ping successfully in both directions.  From a regular GCE instance, I can do an nslookup successfully.

Comment: And I can curl pages inside the cluster from the other network without issue.  It's only DNS from within the cluster that's the problem.